# All website data not show transactions with userId

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a view in Google Analytics called `All website data` that should show all my data, as well as a `User-ID` view.

The problem is when I'm sending transactions from the backend with clientId and userId, this particular transaction does not show in `All website data`. I see it only in the `User-ID` view.

When I'm sending transactions with clientId only, they all show up in `All website data` normally.

Could someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] and describe the issues for example show us the output you get vs what you would expect.

Comment: show an example of your backend call (measurement protocol string), pls